# How to get a click event on a graph in module shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm new to shiny.

When I try to handle a click or brush event without using modules, everything works ok.
What should I do to make the events work inside the module?
There is simple code

```
#MODULE

plUI <- function(id) {
  tagList(
    selectInput(NS(id, "var"), "Variable", choices = names(mtcars)),
    numericInput(NS(id, "bins"), "bins", value = 10, min = 1),
    plotOutput(NS(id, "hist"), click = "plot_click"),
    verbatimTextOutput("info")
  )
}

plServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    data <- reactive(mtcars[[input$var]])
    output$hist <- renderPlot({
      plot(data(), breaks = input$bins, main = input$var)
    }, res = 96)

    output$info <- renderPrint({
      req(input$plot_click)
      x <- round(input$plot_click$x, 2)
      y <- round(input$plot_click$y, 2)
      cat("[", x, ", ", y, "]", sep = "")
    })
    
  })
}
#------------------------------UI-------------------------------------
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  ui <- fluidPage(
    plUI("p1"),
    
  )
)

#------------------------------SERVER-------------------------------------
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  plServer("p1")
  
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2):

- Instead of `NS(id, "var")` for each id, you can do `ns <- NS(id)` and then use `ns("var")` and so on.
- `plot_click` is also an id so wrap it in `ns` as well.
- You had forgotten `NS` in `verbatimTextOutput("info")`.
- The main `ui` had two `fluidPage` that probably was by mistake so removed it.

```
library(shiny)

plUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    selectInput(ns("var"), "Variable", choices = names(mtcars)),
    numericInput(ns("bins"), "bins", value = 10, min = 1),
    plotOutput(ns("hist"), click = ns("plot_click")),
    verbatimTextOutput(ns("info"))
  )
}

plServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    ns <- session$ns
    
    data <- reactive(mtcars[[input$var]])
    
    output$hist <- renderPlot({
      plot(data(), breaks = input$bins, main = input$var)
    }, res = 96)
    
    output$info <- renderPrint({
      req(input$plot_click)
      x <- round(input$plot_click$x, 2)
      y <- round(input$plot_click$y, 2)
      cat("[", x, ", ", y, "]", sep = "")
    })
  })
}
#------------------------------UI-------------------------------------
ui <- fluidPage(
    plUI("p1")
)

#------------------------------SERVER-------------------------------------
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  plServer("p1")
  
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]